# Show that $\int^{2}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\sin(x))\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions. Show that

$$\int^{2}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})\,\mathrm{d}x=0=\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\sin(x))\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I cannot apply substitution method because I don't know if continuity holds for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: You do know that $y=\sin x$ and $y=(x-1)^2$ are differentiable, that's all you need to use substitution.

Comment: Is the integral with $f$ supposed to be from $0$ to $2$? Otherwise, this is clearly false

Comment: @Vasya we need continuity of f or g to apply substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Note, with $x = 2-u$,

$$\int^{2}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx=\int^{1}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx+\int^{2}_{1}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx$$
$$=\int^{1}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx+\int^{0}_{1}(1-u)f((1-u)^{2})(-du)$$
$$=\int^{1}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx-\int^{1}_{0}(u-1)f((u-1)^{2})du = 0$$

And, with $x = \pi -t$,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\sin x)\cos x dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}g(\sin x)\cos x dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}g(\sin x )\cos x dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}g(\sin x )\cos x dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{0}g(\sin t)(-\cos t)(-dt)$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}g(\sin x )\cos x dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}g(\sin t)\cos t dt =0$$

Comment: Is it not $\int^{0}_{1}(1-u)f((1-u)^{2})(-du) = \int^{0}_{1} (u-1)f((1-u)^{2})du $ ? Then we will have $=\int^{1}_{0}(x-1)f((x-1)^{2})dx+\int^{0}_{1}(u-1)f((u-1)^{2})du = 0$

Comment: @Sesame - it is. Then $\int_1^0 ... =-\int_0^1 ...$